# Is it possible to add a new property to existing JSON data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following JSON data:

```
$scope.users = [{ "id": 1, "first_name": "Philip",  "country": "Indonesia" },
                { "id": 2, "first_name": "Judith", "country": "China" },
                { "id": 3, "first_name": "Julie",  "country": "Finland"},
                { "id": 4, "first_name": "Gloria",  "country": "Indonesia"}}];
```

and I want to add a new property like this:

```
$scope.users = [{ "id": 1, "first_name": "Philip",  "country": "Indonesia", "new_field":4 },
                { "id": 2, "first_name": "Judith", "country": "China","new_field":4 },
                { "id": 3, "first_name": "Julie",  "country": "Finland","new_field":4},
                { "id": 4, "first_name": "Gloria",  "country": "Indonesia","new_field":4}}];
```

Is this possible? If yes, how can do this?

Comment: cast data to dynamic list. and just add a new dynamic property.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.users.length;i++)
    $scope.users[i].new_field =4;
```